# Correct Ternary Mapping?

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, ternary

I want to create an Entity-Relationship-Modell for my Database. But i have Problems with thr ternary Relationship. How should this look like for the sql code below?

ternary Relationship[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrkNG.png)

```
CREATE TABLE sell(
employee_id INTEGER,
serial_number CHAR(9),
customer_id INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (serial number),
FOREIGN KEY(employee_id) REFERENCES Employee(employee_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(serial_number) REFERENCES Product(serial_number) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES Customer(customer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365870/er-diagram-ternary-relationship-how-to-read-properly

Comment: serial_number? char(9)?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson from what i have understand my Relationship has to look like this 1:1:n? (n for Products)

Comment: @jarlh should i take Integer?